# How to switch back to autofocus while recording video?

Tags: iphone, camera

If I'm recording a video on my iPhone, it autofocuses by default

If I tap somewhere on the screen, a yellow square appears and it switches to manual focus

Is there a way to switch back to autofocus **in the middle of recording a video**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least currently (in 2021; iOS 14), you can’t directly re-enable continuous autofocus during a recording once you have clicked on the screen (and thus switched to what traditional cameras often call “single autofocus”) using the built-in iOS “Camera” app. As others have said, you can tap on the screen to automatically focus on a new spot (which also exits AE/AF lock mode, if it was enabled), but again, that process stops as soon as focus has been achieved (i.e. it sets up a new AF lock at that distance and begins using the new area for AE exposure metering).

An option that may work in some circumstances: double-tapping on either the record button or one of the physical volume buttons (on the iPhone itself or on Apple-compatible wired^ earbuds / headphones … with the latter you don’t risk jostling the phone if it is mounted) will quickly stop and re-start the recording and therefore re-enable continuous autofocus. The gap in the video should be no larger than the normal autofocus delay; I recommend practicing this method yourself to get the timing right … if the two taps / clicks are *too* quick, they may only be recognized as one.

Finally, various third-party free or paid apps (e.g. FiLMiC Pro [1] [2]) do seem to offer the ability to re-enable continuous autofocus while recording.

Good luck, and happy recording!

---

^ This *may* also work for wireless earbuds / headphones, but I have no experience either way - again, feel free to test with your specific setup.

[1] https://apps.apple.com/us/app/filmic-pro-video-camera/id436577167

[2] https://momofilmfest.com/how-to-use-focus-for-cinematic-video-filmic-pro-tutorial/

Comment: Thanks, I will try one of the 3rd party cameras

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that there is a way to force it to autofocus but it will re-focus if you don't touch it again.

From [Apple Support:](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT207260)

> Your camera automatically focuses the image and adjusts the exposure based on what you’re pointing it towards. That way, you always start with a brightly lit photo.
> You can change the camera focus and exposure to a specific area. Before you take the photo, tap the place on the screen that you want to adjust. If you want to keep the focus and exposure in the same spot, press and hold on the screen until you see AE/AF Lock.

Comment: I think in old versions of iOS I could shake the camera and it would revert to autofocus but it doesn't seem  to revert to autofocus anymore while recording video, no matter how long you wait or how much things are out of focus